# Shift m*n image matrix on matlab to the right

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I currently have a m*n image matrix of gray scale dots. I want to shift the image to the right by a certain number of pixels. The following code seems to both shift it to the right and up. How can I fix this? I need to do some sort of matrix operation to do the shift so built in functions will not work.

```
% Performs a shift on an input image matrix
function shift(CBout, matrix)    
    [m,n]=size(CBout);
    T=ones(m,n)*200;

    CBout = T+CBout;

    plot(CBout(1,:), CBout(2,:), 'k.');
    scale = 400;
    axis([-scale scale -scale scale])
end
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Unless Matlab can optimize your code, that kind of shift would mean allocating memory for the new (and larger) data and copy old data to new data. Memory allocation is slow. It is better to just change your interpretation of the data (in your mind) without doing anything to it (with the computer). I guess your goal is to keep on adding row to it and you know the final size of the array. If that is the case, it is better to just create one large matrix with the final size, and then fill in the rows of that large matrix.

Comment: Have you considered using [`circshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html)?.  In your case, it would be `circshift(CBout, 200, 2)` if I'm reading what you want to do correctly.

Comment: @rayryeng that is a much better solution... however I was doing this for a linear algebra class that would only allow me to perform matrix operations on the CBout matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I just create a ones vector and then added that to the first row of the mxn matrix.

```
% Performs a shift on an input image matrix
function shift(CBout, amount)
    disp('Shifting...');

    n = size(CBout, 2);
    T=ones(1,n)*amount;

    % Add shift amount to every element in the first row
    CBout = [CBout(1,:)+T; CBout(2,:)];

    plot(CBout(1,:), CBout(2,:), 'k.');
    scale = 400;
    axis([-scale scale -scale scale])
end
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to create an array of ones. You can just add by the scalar `amount`. MATLAB is intelligent enough to figure out you're offsetting all values in a matrix by a fixed amount.